# Не запускаются тесты JDBC c бд H2

Tags: spring, jdbc, junit

Пишу Spring MVC приложение. В качестве основной БД использую PostgreSQL, но для тестов решил поднять базу Н2. Для тестов используется отдельная конфигурация Spring. С основной базой мои сервисы работают, а с тестовой нет. Не могу понять в чём причина. Ошибка наверняка незначительная, но опыта чтобы её найти не хватает.

Dependencies

```
dependencies {

    //Spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '5.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.2.5.RELEASE'

    //Data base
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.12'
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'


    //Tests
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '3.3.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.2.5.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.6.2'
```

testConfig

```
package com.johnpank.notestorage.config;

import com.johnpank.notestorage.dao.NoteDAO;
import com.johnpank.notestorage.dao.NoteDAOImpl;
import com.johnpank.notestorage.dao.UserDAO;
import com.johnpank.notestorage.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Objects;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.johnpank.notestorage")
@PropertySource("classpath:appProperties.properties")
public class TestAppConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource testDataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("test.db.driver")));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("test.db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("test.db.userName"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("test.db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    UserDAO testUserDao(){
        return new UserDAOImpl(testDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    NoteDAO testNoteDao(){
        return new NoteDAOImpl(testDataSource());
    }
}
```

Конфиг самого приложения отличается только названием полей properties.

test

```
package com.johnpank.notestorage.dao;

import com.johnpank.notestorage.config.TestAppConfig;
import com.johnpank.notestorage.models.Note;
import com.johnpank.notestorage.models.User;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestAppConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class UserDAOImplTest {


    @Autowired
    private UserDAO testUserDao;

//    @Before
//    public void setUp(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
//        userDao = new UserDAOImpl(dataSource);
//    }
//
//    @After
//    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
//        userDao = null;
//    }

    @Test
    public void createUser() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUser_id(1);
        user.setLogin("logiiin");
        user.setPassword("passsssssword");
        user.setEmail("eeeeeeemaillll");
        user.setReg_date(new Date());
        user.setNotes(new ArrayList<Note>());
        int result = testUserDao.createUser(user);
        assertEquals(1,result);
    }

    @Test
    public void getUserById() {
    }

    @Test
    public void getUserByLogin() {
    }

    @Test
    public void updateUser() {
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteUser() {
    }
}
```

properties

```
#DataBase
db.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
db.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/note_storage_db
db.userName = qqq
db.password = qqq

test.db.driver = org.h2.Driver
test.db.url = jdbc:h2:mem:default
test.db.userName = 1
test.db.password = 1
```

Результат

```
Testing started at 21:49 ...
> Task :cleanTest
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE

> Task :test FAILED






FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.johnpank.notestorage.dao.UserDAOImplTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
6 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 4 up-to-date
```

Comment: Ошибка в чем? Где вывод?

Comment: Добавил результат.